# Still getting invalid product identifiers... iOS

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I keep getting invalid product identifiers as a return from in app purchase product requests.

I've checked the following:

1. Checked provisioning profiles, deleted and re-made several times...
2. Checked product identifiers against products in itunesconnect (uk.co.companyname.appname.product_name).
3. Deleted app and provisions from phone and re installed.
4. Logged out of app store on phone.
5. Checked my code signing (signed as iPhone Developer (with uk.co.companyname.appname as identifier)
6. Made sure app identifier is in info.plist correctly.
7. Submitted and rejected app binary.
8. Running on phone, not simulator.

This is my code for fetching products:

```
- (void)loadProducts
{
    NSSet *productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObjects:uk.co.companyname.appname.product_name, uk.co.companyname.appname.product_name2, uk.co.companyname.appname.product_name3, nil];

    for(NSString *pk in productIdentifiers) NSLog(@"%@", pk);

    SKProductsRequest *productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
    productsRequest.delegate = self;
    [productsRequest start];
}

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"products: %d", [response.products count]);
    NSLog(@"invalidProductIdentifiers: %d", [response.invalidProductIdentifiers count]);
}
```

and I get:

```
products: 0
invalidProductIdentifiers: 9
```